# ConTeXt TABLEs, how to automatically fit table size with text with \setupTABLE

Tags: tables, formatting, context, dimensions

When I type something like

```
\bTABLE
\bTR\bTD abc\eTD\bTD abcdefg\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD 123456789\eTD\bTD 1234\eTD\eTR
\eTABLE
```

in ConTeXt, it automatically sets the column widths to fit the text contained within, like so:

[image: What I want]

This is the exactly the output that I want to see. The problem I have is that, in some documents, I use the \setupTABLE command elsewhere to set the TABLE width manually. After I've done that, I don't know how to revert *back* to this default behaviour. This is what I mean:

[image: What I don't want]

What's the proper way of achieving the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the effect of `\setupTABLE` using it after `\bTABLE`

```
\starttext

\bTABLE
\bTR\bTD abc\eTD\bTD abcdefg\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD 123456789\eTD\bTD 1234\eTD\eTR
\eTABLE



\bTABLE
\setupTABLE[c][each][width=1in]
\bTR\bTD 1inch\eTD\eTR
\eTABLE


\bTABLE
\bTR\bTD This\eTD\bTD more\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD like\eTD\bTD it\eTD\eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer so that it matches with the ConTeXt style. I hope that you don't mind the edit.

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the edit! Of course I don't mind it :)

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to deal with this is to use `setups`:

```
\startsetups name
   \setupTABLE[...][...]
    ....
\stopsetups
```

where `name` can be any string.

Then, you can use

```
\bTABLE[setups=name]
 ....
\eTABLE
```

and context will apply the setup `name`. You can even define multiple setups and select them using

```
\bTABLE[setups={one, two}]
 ....
\eTABLE
```

etc.

Comment: Hi Aditya. That's an interesting feature. I didn't know it before. I'm going to +1 your answer.

With my original question though, I was wondering how one would specify auto-fit table width EXPLICITLY inside a setup, (thus reverting the previous width setting) like \setupTABLE[width=automatic] or something. I tried searching for it and couldn't find it anywhere. Either that, or some way of *removing* the previous \setupTABLE---I don't know if ConTeXt has something like \resetTABLEsetup. I'll award the Accepted Answer to someone who knows how to do either.